Unable to declare a function to reset the syntax
I have created the following functions to reset the syntax
~/.vim/autoload/dan.vim
export def SyntaxOff(): void
    execute 'source' expand('$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/nosyntax.vim')
enddef

export def SyntaxOn(): void
    execute 'source' expand('$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/syntax.vim')
enddef

export def SyntaxReset(): void
    SyntaxOff()
    sleep 2
    SyntaxOn()
enddef

:call dan#SyntaxReset()
Doesn't work, as expected, it justs executes the sleep statement
Though doing :call dan#SyntaxOff() and :call dan#SyntaxOn() works
I have re-written the function the following ways unsucessfully
export def SyntaxReset(): void
    syntax off
    sleep 2
    syntax on
enddef

export def SyntaxReset(): void
    source $VIMRUNTIME/syntax/nosyntax.vim
    sleep 2
    source $VIMRUNTIME/syntax/syntax.vim
enddef

export def SyntaxReset(): void
    execute 'source' expand('$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/nosyntax.vim')
    sleep 2
    execute 'source' expand('$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/syntax.vim')
enddef

I guess I am missing a big point in here on how the syntax files get sourced, yet I need to achieve this functionality.
Is there any way to do it?

Welcome to [vi.se]!

Syntax is reset by the command syntax reset. There's no need to pack it (or other commands) into functions.
If you're curious about internal implementation than you can figure it by exploring Vim source code. It's pretty simple:
let g:syntax_cmd = "reset"
source $VIMRUNTIME/syntax/syntax.vim

Pretty much the same goes for syntax on and syntax enable. There's no need to add anything else to this.
